# Copy column from another table with 'where'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2

Table1

```
id          name        value     source
----------- ----------- -----  ------------
1           a           4          10
2           b           5          10
3           c           6          11
```

Table2

```
      set         text      
    ----------- ----------- 
      7           h                        
      8           g
```

I want to copy the 'value' column to Table2 from Table1,  `where table1.source = 10`

```
      set         text        value 
    ----------- ----------- ---------
      7           h              4        
      8           g              5
```

I tried this:

```
 ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD value INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

            UPDATE tb2
            SET tb1.value = tb2.value
            from Table2 tb2
            JOIN Table1 tb1 
            ON tb1.source=10
```

it has given me this :

```
    id          name        value    
  ----------- ----------- ---------
     7           h           4          
     8           g           4
```

It's updating Table2 rows with only the first `source` value from Table1.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have Microsoft SQL, That's why it's not generating any error.

Comment: . . Noted.   When asking questions please tag appropriately.

Comment: You don't have enough information in the two tables to join them so that `set ` 7 relates to `value` 4 and 8 =>5. This is why you end up with both set to 4. You need to yell the SQL engine how to "connect" the rows, as in a table there is no implied order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sQL server ,use the below query to update the table2.
Note that the script is specific to the given sample data.

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
ADD value INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO

WITH cte_data
as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [set])RNo,*
FROM Table2 )

UPDATE c
SET c.Value=t.Value
FROM cte_data c
JOIN    Table1 t on c.RNo=t.Id
WHERE t.Source=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
insert into table2 (value) select (value) from table1 where table1.source = 10
```

Just add new "value" field in "table2" and try this approach.

Comment: This creates two new rows in Table2 with NULL columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need a row number for the join.  I would advise putting this in both tables:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
       SELECT tb1.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source ORDER BY id) as seqnum
       FROM table1 tb1
      )
UPDATE toupdate
     SET tb1.value = tb2.value
     FROM toupdate tb1 JOIN
          (SELECT tb2.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY set) as seqnum
           FROM table2 tb2
          ) tb2
          ON tb2.seqnum = tb1.seqnum
     WHERE tb1.source = 10;
```